# Change line color when combining graphs

Tags: matlab

I am combining two graphs/plots into one like this:

```
fig1 = open('fig1.fig')
fig2 = open('fig2.fig')

ax1 = get(fig1, 'Children');
ax2 = get(fig2, 'Children');

for i = 1 : numel(ax2)
   ax2Name = get(ax2(i), 'Children');
   copyobj(ax2Name, ax1(i));
end
```

Is it possible to modify (change) the line colors that exist in fig2? The plot has 3 lines in different colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = 1:0.1:5;
y1 = x.^2;
y2 = sqrt(x);
y3 = sin(x);

figure;
plot(x, y1, x, y2);
fig1 = gcf;
ax1 = fig1.Children; % same as get(fig1, 'Children')
line1 = ax1.Children;

figure;
plot(x, y3);
fig2 = gcf;
ax2 = fig2.Children

for l = line1 % iterate over Line array
    copyobj(l, ax2) % copy each Line object from ax1 to ax2
end

disp(ax2.Children)
line2 = ax2.Children;
line2(1).Color = [1 0 0]; % first line (^2): red
line2(2).Color = [0 1 0]; % second line (sqrt): green
line2(3).Color = [0 0 1]; % third line (sine): blue
```

Comment: If one plot has 3 lines with different colors, is it possible to only change one specific line?

Comment: I don't know how there are ordered. Except that, `c(1)`: first line, `c(2)`: second line, `c(3)`: third line. `set(c(3), 'Color', [0 1 0])` set the third to green.

Comment: I am a little unsure how to combine this with the example I provided in my post. Would it be possible to fit my example?

Comment: No worries, I solved it with set(c(3), 'Color', [0 1 0]. Just had to set it to: set(ax2Speed(2), 'Color', [0 1 0]). Many thanks for the help!

Comment: See edited code. But still I can't get how they are reordered.